# Integer variable changing value in C when it's not supposed to

Tags: c, unix, integer

I have no idea what's going on here. A project I am working on is the 2048 game. I am programming it in c. The thing is, I initially declared the score as 0 and have not implemented the scoring system yet but randomly it changes to 4? (I have it printed out)

Here's part of my code:

```
  for(;;){
    printf("Score: %d",user_score);
    rand_i=rand()%(board_size+1);
    rand_j=rand()%(board_size+1);
    while(M[rand_i][rand_j]!=0){
            rand_i=rand()%(board_size+1);
            rand_j=rand()%(board_size+1);
    }
    rand_num= rand()%2*2+2;
    M[rand_i][rand_j]=(rand_num);
    for(i=0;i<board_size;i++){
            printf("\n");
            for(j=0;j<board_size;j++){
                    if (M[i][j]==0){
                            printf("[    ]");
                    }
                    else printf("[%4d]",M[i][j]);
            }
    }
    printf("\n(w=up, a=left, s=down, d=right, q=quit) > ");
    scanf("%c%c",&user_input);
    //system("clear");
    switch(user_input){
            case 'w':
                    for(j=0;j<board_size;j++){
                            for(i=0;i<board_size;i++){
                                    if(M[i][j]!=0 && i!=0){
                                           for(k=i;k>0;k--){
                                                    if(M[k-1][j]==0){
                                                            M[k-1][j]=M[k][j];
                                                            M[k][j]=0;
```

Comment: Variables changing their values when they shouldn't sounds as if you were writing out of biounds in an array, thereby corrupting data elsewhere. You are under Unix, so you should consider running your program through Valgrind, which will tell you about such errors.

Comment: At a glance I see lines such as `rand_i=rand()%(board_size+1)`, where `rand_i´ might end up being `baord_size`, which is one item beyond the board size. n C, array indices run from 0 up to, _but not including_ the array size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are writing beyond array M.

```
rand_i=rand()%(board_size+1);
rand_j=rand()%(board_size+1);
```

If M is declared as int M[board_size][board_size], than rand_i and rand_j could be one too large.

Hope this helps.